# unknown provider in my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to put the HTTP request in a service file in order to use this function in multiple controllers but I get the error below, I tried multiple solutions but still get this error

here is my controller.js

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/LatestMovies', {
templateUrl: 'LatestMovies/LatestMovies.html',
controller: 'LatestMoviesCtrl'

});
}])


.controller('LatestMoviesCtrl', 
['myServices','$scope',function(myServices,$scope) {



$scope.movies = myServices.getLatestMovies();
console.log($scope.movies ,'ggg')
}
]);
```

here is my services.js

```
   angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

 .factory('myServices', function ($http) {
return {
    getLatestMovies : function () {
            var service ={
                movies : '',
                details : []
            }
            var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
            var service = '/movie/popular?page=1&language=en- 
             US&api_key=';
            var apiKey = '';
            var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK';
            var url =base + service + apiKey + '&callback=' + callback;
            //$scope.results = 'requesting...';

            $http.jsonp(url).then(function(result, status) {
                //$scope.results = JSON.stringify(data);
                service.movies = result.data;
                angular.forEach(result.data.results, function (value, 
                index) {
                    service.details.push(value);
                });

            },function(result, status) {
                service.movies = 'Maybe you missed your API key?' + 
       JSON.stringify(result.data);
            });

            return service.movies;
        }
    }

    });
```

error

angular.js:14199 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myServicesProvider <- myServices <- LatestMoviesCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/unpr?p0=myServicesProvider%20%3C-%20myServices%20%3C-%20LatestMoviesCtrl
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4563:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4716:32)
    at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4568:45
    at getService (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4716:32)
    at injectionArgs (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4741:58)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4783:18)
    at $controller

Answer (score 1):

you need to inject the $http module to send api call

```
 .factory('myServices', ['$http',function ($http) {
return {
    getLatestMovies : function () {
            var service ={
                movies : '',
                details : []
            }
            var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
            var service = '/movie/popular?page=1&language=en- 
             US&api_key=';
            var apiKey = '';
            var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK';
            var url =base + service + apiKey + '&callback=' + callback;
            //$scope.results = 'requesting...';

            $http.jsonp(url).then(function(result, status) {
                //$scope.results = JSON.stringify(data);
                service.movies = result.data;
                angular.forEach(result.data.results, function (value, 
                index) {
                    service.details.push(value);
                });

            },function(result, status) {
                service.movies = 'Maybe you missed your API key?' + 
       JSON.stringify(result.data);
            });

            return service.movies;
        }
    }

    }]);
```

Comment: OP is already injected `$http` in his service, you only used `Array Inline Annotation` of DI.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have been creating `myApp` module twice, first in `services.js` and then in `controller.js`. So basically what happens is

1. When `services.js` loaded first, it creates `myApp` angular module with `myServices` service.
2. And when `controllers.js` file loaded, at the beginning of file you have recreated `myApp` module using `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])`. Where it recreate a new `myApp` module and register `config` & `LatestMoviesCtrl` to it.
3. Hence `myServices` dependency isn't available.

To fix the issue while registering further files.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(...)
.controller('LatestMoviesCtrl', .... )
```

Comment: you mean i should remove angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']) from myservice.js and keep the one in my controller

Comment: removing `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])` part totally depends on in what sequence you loaded js files? did you load `services.js` first?

Comment: the controller load first and call the service file

Comment: I'm asking about js references sequence on the html page? If `services.js` referenced first then use `angular.module('myApp')` on page `controllers.js`.

Comment: i got a blank page